# What are these formulas that are suppose to be Gram-Schmidt

Tags: linear-algebra

The formulas are in this picture.
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4o78y.png]

My question is what are these formulas used for. I tried using them but they don't work. I'm familiar with Gram-Schmidt but these don't look like GRAM. I got these formulas from 3D Game Programming with DirectX 11.

The book says:

In §1.3.1, we looked at a way to orthogonalize a set of vectors using the process. For 3D, there is another strategy to orthogonalize a
set of vectors {Gram-Schmidtv0, v1, v2} that are almost orthonormal, but perhaps became un-orthonormal due to accumulated
numerical precision errors, using the cross product. Refer to Figure 1.15 for the geometry of this process:

Comment: Please use LaTeX to show the formulae.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming the third equation is $\textbf{W}_1 = \textbf{W}_0 \times \textbf{W}_2$.

Those three equations are just another way to obtain an orthonormal basis of vector for $\mathbb{R}^3$. For higher dimensions, one will have to generalize the cross product, which is much more of a hassle than the Gram-Schmidt process.

The first equation normalizes one of our vectors $\textbf{v}_0$, and sets it equal to $\textbf{W}_0$. The second equation produces a vector orthogonal to $\textbf{v}_1$ and $\textbf{W}_0$, and normalizes it also, setting it equal to $\textbf{W}_2$.

Now you have two orthonormal vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$. A way to get a third is to take the cross product of the two.